# Date versioning and restoring

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-versioning

We are developing a SAAS based application. One of the requirements is to record every change in database tables i.e. create date/time based version of data. Client should be able to revert back to any version of data.

I have almost 30 tables in database, and data insertion frequency is 80,000 records added/updated per day through bulk import. However, client can also use GUI to insert data through forms (other than bulk import).

Before creating any strategy to implement this requirement, I would love have your comments/suggestion on how to implement this.

On a side note, I have reviewed [this blog post](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2009/11/29/versioned-data/) and found it very good starting point but I still doubt on how to restore past data.

Database snapshot is a promising solution, but as I said earlier that this is a SAAS based application and we are storing multiple clients data in a single database, and snapshot would restore data for other clients as well.

Please suggest any strategy/plan on how to execute this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using JPA/Hibernate to fetch your data, you can give Envers a shot.

Envers is a JBoss open-source project for maintaining versions of Database Entities. You can mark certain columns of the entire table with `@Audited` annotation to start tracking audit history. It typically stores all the audit data in a table with _AUDIT name. It also provides API to query historical data.

For details please go thru http://www.jboss.org/envers

Comment: We are planning to move onto Spring framework so I guess we will use Hibernate as ORM. Our main concern is huge amount of data in associative tables, which we have to version as well. Secondly, revert data back to any version.